# Xamarin MvvmCross initialize popup menu in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Is it possible to initialize popup menu in a ViewModel?

[image]

For now I'm initializing it on View like this:

```
var button = activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.moreButton);

button.Click += (s, arg) =>
{
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(activity, button);
    menu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.PopupMenu);
    menu.Show();

    menu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg1) =>
    {
        switch (arg1.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString())
        {
            case "Profile":
                activity.StartActivity(typeof(ProfileView));
                break;
            case "Prices":
                break;
            case "Terms":
                activity.StartActivity(typeof(TermsView));
                break;
            case "Privacy":
                activity.StartActivity(typeof(PrivacyView));
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

But in my .axml files I want to bind "Open Popup Menu" button with `MvxBind` and so it would work. How can I do this?

**UPDATE 1**

Or maybe it is possible to bind clicks on xml file like this, because now it's not working obviously...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:title="Profile"
    local:MvxBind="Click GoProfileCommand"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/prices"
    android:title="Prices"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/terms"
    android:title="Terms"
    local:MvxBind="Click GoTermsCommand"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/privacy"
    android:title="Privacy"
    local:MvxBind="Click GoPrivacyCommand"/>
```